# aspectj-maven-plugin not weaving if sourceDirectory is set?

Tags: maven, aspectj, maven-3

### Question

I have trouble weaving some aspects during compile time since I added the sourceDirectory tag with "src/main/java" as path. Before "." was set. Now the aspects are not weaved into the classes.

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        ...
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
        <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
        <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>                    
        <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
      </plugins>
  </build>
```

It seems that the weaving gets skipped. If I set "." for sourceDirectory it will work again and aspectj will produce some output.

### Solution

Oh man, it's friday afternoon...

For all running in same issue:

- check that the directory of your aspects is **"src/main/aspect"** and not "src/main/aspects" or set the aspectDirectory parameter for plugin to know where your aspects are
- check that if you used extension ".aj" for your aspects tell the plugin that he has to include all "*.aj" files
- set the basedir where the plugin could find the java source

Sorry about that one here...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <basedir>src/main/java</basedir>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.aj</include>
                        </includes>
                    </source>
                </sources>              
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>                    
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Why would you set `sourceDirectory` when it looks like you are using the default?

Comment: This is because we configured jenkins with sonar. Sonar is a little bit angry about not knowning the source to java classes. Also IntelliJ forgets about the sources directories all the time we force reimport from maven. (Txh for your very fast reply;)

Comment: Haha, I was just going to post I was having trouble reproducing your issue as my dummy app works fine! Glad you've solved it.

Comment: Nevertheless thanks for your effort!

Comment: @FrankSzilinski Please post the "solution" as an answer and accept it