# Creating a sample AspectJ-project within IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, aspectj, java-11

I'm setting up a project within IntelliJ IDEA based on Maven and AspectJ. Unfortunately, everything tried fails (i.e. the aspect seems to be ignored).

I created the smallest possible testproject with a maven-file. It looks like this:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.nickwongdev</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>de.benchmarktest.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I had to use `aspectj-maven-plugin` from `com.nickwongdev`, to be able to compile with Java 11.

The idea was taken from an example with a simple `Account`-class:

```
package de.benchmarktest;

public class Account {

    int balance = 20;

    public boolean withdraw(int amount) {
        balance -= amount;
        return true;
    }

}
```

The `AccountAspect.aj` looks like this:

```
package de.benchmarktest;

public aspect AccountAspect {
    pointcut callWithDraw(int amount, Account acc) :
            call(boolean de.benchmarktest.Account.withdraw(int)) && args(amount) && target(acc);

    boolean around(int amount, Account acc) :
            callWithDraw(amount, acc) {
        if (acc.balance < amount) return false;
        return proceed(amount, acc);
    }

}
```

If I now construct a sample Main-method like so:

```
package de.benchmarktest;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account acc = new Account();
        System.out.println(acc.withdraw(10));
        System.out.println(acc.withdraw(20));
    }

}
```

I'd guess the output should be `true`, followed by `false`. Infact, it is two times `true`. Therefore the Aspect seems not to be triggered.

If running the compilation manually from the console via `mvn package`, I get `[WARNING] No sources found skipping aspectJ compile`. How do I teach the system to run the Aspects on compiling the sourcecode? Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Comment: [RTFM](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/aspectj.html)

Comment: Dear Victor, thanks for your input. Of course I tried changing the compiler. Still the result is the same. But I got at least a bit of progress: When manually compiling via `mvn package`, I can run the program from within the IDEA. If afterwards deleting the target-folder, the output is again two times true.

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365410/aspectj-maven-plugin-not-weaving-if-sourcedirectory-is-set Make sure the directory where your aspects are is processed.

Comment: Adding the sources-tag leads to the whole files not being processed even when compiling manual via terminal. So I guess, that could be a good starting point. I do have the basedir `src/main/java` but it seems to not be the right configuration for my project. Any way to debug that?

Comment: **Addition:** Even stranger: Switching to @AspectJ-Style works when using `mvn package` and `mvn exec:java` flawlessly - but hitting "Run" inside the IDE (of course with `ajc`) generates only an error-message: `Error:Module 'benchmarktest' production: org.aspectj.bridge.AbortException: can't determine superclass of missing type java.lang.Object
 [Xlint:cantFindType]`

Comment: Two questions before I install JDK 11 just in order to test this: (1) Does the same setup work with Java 8 and IDEA? I want to avoid this being an IDEA issue. (2) Do you use a standard Maven directory layout, e.g. code under _src/main/java_? It would be nice if you could publish your sample project on GitHub for me to clone and build.

Comment: One more bit of information: I was curious, installed Oracle JDK 11 and latest Maven 3.6.0, added the SDK to IDEA and switched an existing AspectJ project to use JDK 11 as well as the forked AspectJ Maven plugin, and it works fine. After updating the Java compiler settings to use Ajc 1.9.2 instead of Javac or an older AspectJ version, it now also works when compiling and running the project directly from IDEA. So there are no unsolvable issues. I do need more information in order to help you. My IDEA version is 2018.3.4 Ultimate.